# In cypress testing how to check if these tiles are in order?

Tags: javascript, cypress

There are multiple chapters on a page in a format as shown in the image. I have to add a test in cypress which checks if chapter numbers are in order. In case they get shuffled (as shown in image), the test should show an error.

Also the text "Chapter 1" can be selected so cypress can read it on the screen. These tiles have other information as well but I only want the chapter number tested.

[image]

Edit: Updated Picture
[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code please. Also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to check is by extracting all the numbers from each tile and checking if the original array is the same as the sorted array.

```js
cy.get(".tile-selector:contains('Lesson Number')")
  .then(($el) => {
    // use lodash .map() to get innerText of each element
    // then extract number and convert to int
    const originalOrder = Cypress._.map($el, (n) => {
      // get number only, in this case will be index 2
      return +n.innerText.split(" ")[2];
    });
    // make a copy of the original array to sort
    const sortedOrder = [...originalOrder];
    // use comparator to sort numbers
    sortedOrder.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    expect(originalOrder, "Chapters are in order").to.deep.equal(sortedOrder);
  });
```

Here is an [example](https://github.com/jjhelguero/cypress-examples/blob/main/cypress/e2e/checkOrder.md).

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm somewhat looking for this solution but in my case each tile also have other information like Grade, Semester, etc. which are also numbers. Is there a way to only select the "Lesson Number" text and do it?

Comment: Yes, to only look for tiles with beginning with 'Lesson Number' only it would be best to use the jQuery `:contains()` selector. The selector in my answer has been updated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean 'Lesson Number' but 'Chapter Number'. I've uploaded a new image which will give clear idea. Also there are 100s of chapters so I can't define an order. So I want a test like card 2 > card 1. Card 3 > card 2 and so on based on chapter numbers. For example, first 2 cards are correct as Chapter 8 > Chapter 5 but next 2 will give error as Chapter 1 < Chapter 8. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to just compare the combined texts

```js
const expectedText = 'Chapter 1Chapter 3Chapter 5Chapter 13';

cy.get(selector)                                         // all the chapter cards
  .invoke('text')                                        // get combined text
  .should('eq', expectedText)
```

If you find there is white-space and linefeeds (\n) making the combined comparison difficult, map and trim the individual texts

```js
const expectedOrder = ['Chapter 1', 'Chapter 3', 'Chapter 5', 'Chapter 13'];

cy.get(selector)
  .then($els => $els.toArray().map(el => el.innerText.trim())   // trim whitespace
  .should('deep.eq', expectedOrder)                             // deep.eq for array
```

Use the `deep.equal` assertion to test the order is correct.

Comment: Thanks. This almost works but in my case each tile also have other information like chapter name, Grade, Semester, etc. Is there a way to only select the "Lesson Number" text and do it?